# COALESCE function in SQL Server returns NULL although one argument isn't NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, coalesce, sql-server-2022

I have a list of employees working in different departments.

```
create table emp 
(
    emp_name   varchar(15)   primary key,
    birthdate  date          not null,
    dept_id    integer       not null
);

insert into emp 
values ('Erna',    '1969-01-17', 1),
       ('Peter',   '1970-02-13', 1),
       ('Urs',     '1998-11-07', 1),
       ('Ulli',    '1969-04-15', 1),
       ('Andreas', '2004-06-23', 2),
       ('Vera',    '1995-12-02', 2),
       ('Herta',   '2006-03-03', 3),
       ('Django',  '1997-10-09', 3);
```

Now I want a list of them in the order they are having birthday each year, including the following person who is next to have birthday. Since the last person in the year has no successor, the first person should be named. All this works by department.

```
with cte1 as 
(
    select  
        emp_name, dept_id, birthdate, 
        count(*) over abt as anz_in_abt,
        coalesce(lead(emp_name)  over abt, 
        first_value(emp_name) over abt) as ausr,
        coalesce(lead(birthdate) over abt, 
        first_value(birthdate) over abt) as bd_ausr
    from
        emp
    window abt as (
      partition by dept_id
      order by month(birthdate), day(birthdate)
      -- rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    )
)
select *
from cte1
order by dept_id, month(birthdate), day(birthdate);
```

SQL Server doesn't like the "rows between" clause, so I commented it out. In PostgreSQL and SQLite it works with or without this clause, but SQL Server doesn't show the first person as the successor of the last one in the year for the first two departments, but `NULL` values instead.

```
emp_name|dept_id|birthdate |anz_in_abt|ausr  |bd_ausr   |
--------+-------+----------+----------+------+----------+
Erna    |      1|1969-01-17|         1|Peter |1970-02-13|
Peter   |      1|1970-02-13|         2|Ulli  |1969-04-15|
Ulli    |      1|1969-04-15|         3|Urs   |1998-11-07|
Urs     |      1|1998-11-07|         4|      |          |
Andreas |      2|2004-06-23|         1|Vera  |1995-12-02|
Vera    |      2|1995-12-02|         2|      |          |
Herta   |      3|2006-03-03|         1|Django|1997-10-09|
Django  |      3|1997-10-09|         2|Herta |2006-03-03|
```

Since the syntax for extracting day and month from a date is different in PostgreSQL, I added two functions to make SQL Server's code work.

```
create or replace function month(d date) returns smallint
begin atomic
  select extract(month from d);
end;

create or replace function year(d date) returns smallint
begin atomic
  select extract(year from d);
end;
```

SQLite extracts day and month with strftime(), therefore the code is not exactly the same.

```
with cte1 as (
  select emp_name, dept_id, birthdate, count(*) over abt as anz_in_abt,
    coalesce(lead(emp_name)  over abt, first_value(emp_name) over abt) as ausr, 
    coalesce(lead(birthdate) over abt, first_value(birthdate) over abt) as bd_ausr
    from emp
    window abt as (
      partition by dept_id 
      order by strftime('%m', birthdate), strftime('%d', birthdate)
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    )
)
select *
from cte1 
order by dept_id, strftime('%m', birthdate), strftime('%d', birthdate);
```

The correct result given by PostgreSQL and SQLite is

```
 emp_name | dept_id | birthdate  | anz_in_abt |  ausr   |  bd_ausr   
----------+---------+------------+------------+---------+------------
 Erna     |       1 | 1969-01-17 |          1 | Peter   | 1970-02-13
 Peter    |       1 | 1970-02-13 |          2 | Ulli    | 1969-04-15
 Ulli     |       1 | 1969-04-15 |          3 | Urs     | 1998-11-07
 Urs      |       1 | 1998-11-07 |          4 | Erna    | 1969-01-17
 Andreas  |       2 | 2004-06-23 |          1 | Vera    | 1995-12-02
 Vera     |       2 | 1995-12-02 |          2 | Andreas | 2004-06-23
 Herta    |       3 | 2006-03-03 |          1 | Django  | 1997-10-09
 Django   |       3 | 1997-10-09 |          2 | Herta   | 2006-03-03
```

So, is this a bug in SQL Server 2022?

Comment: *"So, is this a bug in MS SQL Server 2022?"* Yes, it appears to be a bug with *something* (I would suggest the combination of the `CASE`/`COALESCE` and `WINDOW` clause in the same scope;  moving the scope, removing the `WINDOW` clause or using `ISNULL` gives a different result: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/14Igr-GI)). Does that answer your *actual* question though? If your goal is to report the bug you're in the wrong place; [so] has no affliation Microsoft. Bugs with SQL Server are reported on the Azure Feedback Portal.

Comment: Nice find, strange that ISNULL works but not COALESCE

Comment: " If your goal is to report the bug you're in the wrong place; Stack Overflow has no affliation Microsoft. Bugs with SQL Server are reported on the Azure Feedback Portal." No, this is to check whether it is a bug, not reporting it.

Comment: Then the answer is yes. Though, that does little help to anyone..

Comment: It helps me a lot. That is what counts. And it may help other people running into this problem. That's what stackoverflow is for: finding problems and solutions. Here: using isnull() instead of coalesce() or avoding the window clause.

Comment: Actually, it isn't. [So] is a site that strives for questions and answers that help many people, not an individual. So, if you want to do that, you should report the bug.

Comment: @siggemannen it's not really. Though the functions do similar things, they actually are coded completely differently.

Comment: Looks like it, i thought ISNULL was just a COALESCE wrapper

Comment: Nope, they actually behave differently, @siggemannen . Try `ISNULL('ABC',1)` and then `COALESCE('ABC',1)`, for example, or `ISNULL('001',1)` and `COALESCE('001',1)`. `COALESCE` is actually a wrapper for a `CASE` expression.

Comment: Interesting, it seems ISNULL only forces conversion when first arguments is NULL, while COALESCE forces a common datatype on all of it's arguments before starting

Comment: Sort of, @siggemannen , `COALESCE` (read `CASE`) uses data type precedence, while `ISNULL` returns the data type of the *first* parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, is it a bug. You should report it.

To workaround it, don't use `COALESCE`/`CASE` in the same scope as the `WINDOW` clause, don't use a `WINDOW` clause, or use `ISNULL`.

Comment: @HolgerJakobs - posted for you https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/88d7a67b-8fe8-ee11-a73d-0022484c4e0d